# What kind of privilege settings may prevent a user on a Windows machine from updating his Java Deployment trust store

Tags: java, windows, permissions, jnlp, truststore

A user is running a JNLP app which is launched from the browser. The jar file launched by the JNLP is signed by a Certificate issued by a trusted CA. 
The first time the jar file is lanched, the user is asked a question whether he trusts the signer (not the CA - the CA is already trusted.
[image: Question Dialog Box]

When the user says yes, on my machine, I noticed that the signer certificate gets added to this trust store

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs`

However, at a customer site, this trust store doesn't seem to get updated even if the user checks the "Do not show again" checkbox. Why could this be happening? This seems to be a user specific deployment trust store & not the JRE truststore. This trust store is in a directory for which the user should have permissions. So what could be preventing this?

Comment: The Java deployment settings could be stored in the `Roaming` subfolder of the user's profile. File permissions could be changed so that the user cannot write to that folder. That's the only things that come to my mind. (I believe it's too late alredy.)